# How to get separate string on the base of tag in MS Word using VBA?

Tags: vba

I have following string and I want to split it on the base of word.

String:

```
 Your meaning <b>is unclear here</b>: please revise.
```

I want to separate data of string on the base of `<b>` tag

So the result will be like

```
Array[0] = "Your meaning ";
Array[1] = "is unclear here";
Array[2] = ": please revise.";
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried the `Split` function? Why does it not work and what did you try to fix it?

Comment: @arcadeprecinct split function splits on the base of delimiter. Ex. "\", "," etc. I want to separate on the base of tag.

Comment: `Split` also takes more than one character as delimiter. If you don't feel comfortable with that, `Replace` the tags with some single-character delimiter first. (which would also be a workaround for the next problem that will arise)

Comment: @arcadeprecinct Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that you can use:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Remove()

    Dim str_note    As String
    Dim str_arr()   As String
    Dim str_arr2()  As String
    Dim l_counter   As Long
    Dim l_counter2  As Long
    
    str_note = "Your meaning <b>is unclear here</b>: please revise."
    
    str_note = Replace(str_note, ">", "<")
    
    Debug.Print str_note
    str_arr = Split(str_note, "<")
    
    For l_counter = 0 To UBound(str_arr)
        If l_counter Mod 2 = 0 Then
            If l_counter <> 0 Then l_counter2 = l_counter2 + 1
            ReDim Preserve str_arr2(l_counter2)
            str_arr2(l_counter2) = str_arr(l_counter)
        End If
    Next l_counter
    
End Sub
```

str_arr2 is the answer.